# 2 different fields when using UNION

Tags: mysql

I want to make 2 queries appear in one result table with 2 fields. wrong_answers and right_answers.

wrong_answers query :

```
select count(ma_id) as wrong_answers
from exercicio natural
join avaliacao natural
join user_sessao
where se_id=4 and us_id=1 and not exists (
    select ma_id
    from grelha natural
    join exercicio natural
    join avaliacao natural
    join user_sessao
    where us_id=1 and se_id=4
)
```

right_answers query :

```
select count(ma_id) as right_answers
from exercicio natural
join avaliacao natural
join user_sessao natural
join grelha where se_id=4 and us_id=1
```

When I do `wrong_answers` query `UNION right_answers` query both results appear in the wrong_answers column.

How can i make them be 2 diff columns?

Thank you

Comment: try using `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an union query in this case, if you want those queries to be in two different columns, you can use this:

```
SELECT
  (
    select count(ma_id) as wrong_answers
    from exercicio
    natural join avaliacao
    natural join user_sessao
    where se_id=4 and us_id=1 and not exists (
       select ma_id
       from grelha
       natural join exercicio
       natural join avaliacao
       natural join user_sessao
       where us_id=1 and se_id=4
    )
  ) AS wrong_answers,
  (
    select count(ma_id) as right_answers
    from exercicio
    natural join avaliacao
    natural join user_sessao
    natural join grelha
    where se_id=4 and us_id=1
  ) AS right_answers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NULL AS correct, count(ma_id) AS wrong
.... wrong answer stuff here

UNION ALL

SELECT count(ma_id), NULL
.... right answer stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` keeps columns from both result sets. If a column is in both queries then it will appear once in the final result set.